# Get info for all features upon click with betterWms Leaflet plugin?

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo, leaflet-plugins

[image] [image]

```
 var layer = L.tileLayer.betterWms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
    layers: 'data',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
}).addTo(map);
```

When adding this **GROUP WMS  Layer** on a base map Leaflet, **onclick** I am getting only one Layer data but **Layer Group** showing well **2 Layer**. I want to get info about both layers on click.

I am using [betterwms.js](https://github.com/jfaraklit/BetterWMS) Leaflet plugin.

[image]

Comment: @TomazicM  its group layer from geoserver and code is also there

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code of Leaflet `betterWms` plugin, you'll see that parameters for `GetFeatureInfo` request are constructed like this:

```
params = {
  request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
  service: 'WMS',
  srs: 'EPSG:4326',
  styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
  transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
  version: this.wmsParams.version,      
  format: this.wmsParams.format,
  bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
  height: size.y,
  width: size.x,
  layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
  query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
  info_format: 'text/html'
};
```

Since there is no `feature_count` parameter, it defaults to 1, and that's the reason why you get info only about one feature.

You'll have to edit plugin code and set this parameter to desired value.

Answer (score 0):

If you host the wms through geoserver, you setup the return info template inside there, with the code to return data for all layers.